# I'm really confused about linear maps and their basis

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm not really sure how to format all this into LaTeX, so I hope an image is acceptable. [The questions at hand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9kQ8.jpg)

So I've done a lot of research, and here is what I understand:

1. The basis of a vector space is if a collection of vectors, A, is the basis for B if A is linearly independent and spans B.
2. The linear map is defined by having properties: T(u+v)=t(u)+t(v) and it holds under scalar multiplication like af(u) = f(au).
3. A vector subspace must adhere to 3 properties: the 0 vector is part of it, it holds under addition, and it holds under scalar multiplication.

From that, however, I'm just completely lost on how to approach problems like this or even solve them. I've tried to apply the above properties, but just don't even know. I hope I can get some help here. Thanks

Here are my thoughts for #1:

For $E_{-1}$, we see that

1. 0=0,
2. it holds under addition, look at the vectors (a,-a,c) and (b,-b,f). We then get (a + b, -a - b, c + f). We observe that a+b = -(a+b), so it is closed under addition.
3. Unsure how to show scalar.

This is similar to $E_{1}$. Thats what I have.

Comment: Welcome. It’s “closed” under addition and scalar multiplication btw. In general we say sets/structures are “closed” under a certain operation if the application of this operation to elements of the set returns elements of the same set. What is the definition of $E_{-1}$ and $E_1$? Although regardless for point $2)$ you need to show linearity over addition for *all* vectors not just for a particular pair

Comment: You are told that the transformation $f$ is linear, so I recommend determining what that corresponding matrix is. Have you learned about eigenvectors yet?

Comment: Hi, thanks for that - I edited the question to attempt to make it generic for all vectors. The definitions of E-1 and E1 are in the photo, with E_-1 = {u  \in R^3, f(u)=-u} and E_1 = {u \in R^3, f(u) = u}. @Joe We have not unfortunately learned about that.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! <> There are multiple inter-related concepts in play here, and the use of pronouns suggests a lack of comfort with the material that would be best addressed by speaking in person to your TA, your professor, or a tutor. <> Note that (i) The problems confusingly use $f$ to denote a linear transformation and a boldface $f$ for vectors. (ii) Whether or not $E_{1}$ and $E_{-1}$ are vector subspaces can be deduced from the fact that $f$ is a linear transformation, regardless of the formulas defining $f$: Can you see why if $f(u)=u$ and $f(v)=v$, then $f(au+v)=au+v$ for all $a$?

Comment: A linear function is completely determined by its action on the basis elements. Look at what happens to the basis vectors under a fixed map and one that outputs the negative of the vector.

Comment: I still think, for #2 especially, you should determine the matrix representation $A$ of the linear transformation $f$, which is rather easy. If you find it, show it here. If you were allowed to use properties of eigenspaces of symmetric matrices, you could use that for #1, but if not, I guess you just need to show that each subspace contains a vector not in the other.

Comment: Hi everyone - thanks for your help. To answer a few things, I think logically the $f(u)=u$ and $f(v)=v$ means $f(au+v)=au+v$ makes sense. I think proving that $E_1$ and $E_{-1}$ being vector subspaces is a matter of proving the scalar multiplication fact, which I am struggling to achieve. As regards for Q2, I am unfamiliar with proving the linear transformation $f?$ being in the vector spaces $E_1$ or $E_{-1}$

Comment: If $\mathbf{u}$ is in $E_1$, what does $f(c\mathbf{u})$ equal?

Comment: In Q2, $\mathbf{f}_1$, $\mathbf{f}_2$, and $\mathbf{f}_3$ are vectors, not linear transformations.

Comment: Thanks everyone - I read through all the posts and was able to solve these two questions with your guys' help!